# Do Mods get Rep for Deleting Downvoted Answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answer

Second time I've seen the same moderator call an answer a "comment" (and delete it), when the real issue is (let's be generous to the moderator here) the quality or correctness of the answer.  Why would a mod delete an answer and call it a comment when it is *clearly* an answer?  If it is a *wrong* answer, that still doesn't make it a comment.

From the rules:

> Why and how are some answers deleted?
>
> Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed.
>   This includes answers that are:
>
> ```
> * commentary on the question or other answers
> * asking another, different question
> * “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
> * exact duplicates of other answers
> * barely more than a link to an external site
> * not even a partial answer to the actual question
> ```

QUESTION: Is there a built-in motivator for mindless clickiness on the part of moderators?  Specifically, is there a reward for deleting down-voted answers and calling them comments?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is lacking examples to provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: I think what's happening here (people asking "What answers are you talking about?") is that they query the premise this question is based on. Without those specific examples the question may be based on incorrect assumptions. The same goes for me, I have no idea what **facts** you are talking about.

Comment: @HaakonDahl that would be me. The comments were getting a bit unconstructive. While I answered your specific question, there is an *implication* that you want someone to answer for deletion actions in the first half of your question. It might be worth modifying your question slightly away from "a moderator deleted *my* answers, so do they get a bonus" to "I've seen answers deleted and just wanted to know *if* there is some incentive..." just something to think about.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. Moderators get no reputation bonus for their actions in any way.

The only way moderators get rep is the same ways that normal users get rep, by getting upvotes on questions and answers, deleting answers is not one of those ways.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer.

Answer (score 5):

To add to @Mokubai's answer - it's not only mods who don't get rep for this. High rep users can also cast delete votes (through the VLQ review queue at 2K reputation and directly at 20K), and do not get any reputation from exercising this privilege.